# How to assign a java array string to a javascript array string?

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, jsp

Below is my code,

```
<select name = "department_select">
    <script language = "javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var dept_names = [];
        var index=0,limit,it;
        <% 
        String dept_list[] = dbManager.get_dept_list();
        for(int i=0;i<dept_list.length;i++)
        {
            %>
            dept_names[<%=i%>] = <%=dept_list[i]%>;
            <%
        }
        %>
        limit = dept_list.length;
        for(index=0;index<limit;index++)
        {                       
            document.write("<option>"+dept_names[index]+                                   "</option>");        
        }
    </script>
</select>
```

I am trying to create a dropdownlist that will access the data from the database and use those data as options of the dropdownlist in the jsp page for a few days now.

When my jsp page is executed it shows the dropdownlist, but there is no option, just blank.

I think assignment at line 10 of the code is not working.

I tried to assign each value of the java array to the javascript array using a loop.

Why this is not working ? I am using oracle database system.

Comment: Why are you spitting out JavaScript and not just spitting out the options to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the JavaScript strings.

Change

```
dept_names[<%=i%>] = <%=dept_list[i]%>;
```

to

```
dept_names[<%=i%>] = "<%=dept_list[i]%>";
```

or simply

```
dept_names.push("<%=dept_list[i]%>");
```

Change also

```
limit = dept_list.length;
```

to

```
limit = dept_names.length;
```

Notes :

- there's no reason here to loop twice, once in Java and once in JS. You could do a simple Java loop to build your options
- it would be cleaner and less tedious to use a JSON encoder to directly write your JS literals from Java. This would also avoid errors (like a `"` in the middle of your string)
- you should declare the variables in JavaScript (`limit`, `index`)

Comment: It didn't work. I have noticed that when I add the quotes the statement--> <%=dept_list[i]%>    inside the quotes is not treated as string. In your solution after adding the quotes the statement changed color from black to red. In my eclipse IDE string type is shown as blue. But after adding the quotes it remains black.....What am I supposed to do now ?

Comment: Never mind. It worked !!!...I changed the code to this-- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7837587/

I guess changing color doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that.